# After clicking a submit button need to select a previous dropdown value

Tags: php

I have dropdown value from database and I have one textbox, submit button too

```
<option value="1">A1</option>
<option value="2">A2</option>
<option value="3">A3</option>
<option value="4">B1</option>
<option value="5">B2</option>
```

After selecting A2 from dropdown value.. I have added General Industries in text box for A2(dropdown value)..... After clicking a submit button. I need to show below A2 Grid values like : General Industries (inside Grid)

My question is.. After clicking a submit button (I reload the same page.. So I need to select dropdown value A2) ... Below show grid values too..

Plz give me some ideas :)

Comment: You can use Ajax to achieve this as you don't even have to reload the page. See $.get and $.post or in general $.ajax

Comment: @Arun Post full code for that

Comment: I am not sure as how you are looking, Initially I assumed you needed to contact a server on click. Now that I read your question again this is what I understood.

See the example if this works then fine if not be more specific in your question.

jsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/vpmBQ/

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
<?php

$postedValue = 0;
if (isset($_POST['foo'])) {
  $postedValue = $_POST['foo'];
}

$options = array(
  1 => 'A1',
  2 => 'A2',
  3 => 'A3',
  4 => 'B1',
  5 => 'B2',
);

?>

<form method="post">
  <select name="foo">
  <?php foreach ( $options as $value => $name ) {
    $selected = $postedValue == $value ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $name . '</option>';
  } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I got dropdown value from database.. I no need in array :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want,

```
jQuery ("option")    .click (function () {
   $this = $(this);
   jQuery ("<input type='text' />").    val ("General Industries").insertAfter ($this);
});
```

then probably fine.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpmBQ/